# How to use ConversionService in SPRINGLETS Select2DataSupport - Spring boot MVC

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, jquery-select2

I have this method in class Controller

```
@Autowired
private ConversionService conversionService;



@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, name = "select2", value = "/siglevmubigeos/s2")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Select2DataSupport<SigLevMUbigeo>> select2(GlobalSearch search, Pageable pageable, Locale locale){
    Page<SigLevMUbigeo> sigLevMUbigeos = sigLevMUbigeoService.findAll(search, pageable);
    String idExpression = "#{pkcubigeo}";
    Select2DataSupport<SigLevMUbigeo> select2Data = new Select2DataWithConversion<SigLevMUbigeo>(sigLevMUbigeos, idExpression, conversionService);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(select2Data);
}
```

Html with Thymeleaf:

```
<select id="fkcubigeo"
        class="form-control input-sm w3-select"
        data-allow-clear="true"                              
        th:field="*{fkcubigeo}">
        <option th:unless="*{fkcubigeo} == null" th:value="*{fkcubigeo.pkcubigeo}" th:text="*{fkcubigeo.cconcatenadistrito}" selected="selected">Ubigeo</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

`$(function() {
     $("#fkcubigeo").select2({
          ajax: {
            url: "/myapp/siglevmubigeos/s2",
            cache: true
          }
        });
     });`

And the result is:

[image]

The method return this data:

```
{"results":[{"id":"010101","text":"com.proviasnac.sigvial.persist.SigLevMUbigeo[ pkcubigeo=010101 ]","info":null},{"id":"010102","text":"com.proviasnac.sigvial.persist.SigLevMUbigeo[ pkcubigeo=010102 ]","info":null},....],"pagination":{"more":false}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ResponseEntity<Select2DataSupport<SigLevMUbigeo>> select2(GlobalSearch search, Pageable pageable) {
    Page<SigLevMUbigeo> data = sigLevMUbigeoService.findAll(search, pageable);
    String idExpression = "#{pkcubigeo}";
    String textExpression = "#{cconcatenadistrito}";
    Select2DataSupport<SigLevMUbigeo> select2Data = new Select2Data<SigLevMUbigeo>(data, idExpression,
            textExpression);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(select2Data);
}
```